# How can we get navigation toggle when more tabs are opened likein Firefox browser

Tags: jquery, firefox

Hi I have a requirement in a `DIV` tag there are tabs loading dynamically from backed.When the tab number exceeds certain width a navigation toggler has to applied similar to Firefox browser as shown below

[image]

How can we acheive this in Jquery.Any plugin is available?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://riteshsblog.blogspot.no/2011/09/jquery-ui-tab-scroller-plugin.html

Comment: If you download the zip file, there is a live example in there